# Facebook graph api returning results in local language

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I came across a funny yet disturbing issue today. I queried for cities to Facebook graph API through my browser and it returned correct results but then i hit the same service it returned same result but it translated one field(country_name) into my local language(Urdu).
I tried different access tokens and gems but result was same. Anyone has any idea how can i get results in English?

here's the api call : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=city&q=new&country_code=US&region_key=3887&access_token=

[here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEbZt.png)

Comment: are you sure all those parameters work? they are not in the docs, only "type" and "q" (for the name).

Comment: yes. i am sending same request using browser and it is returning correct results.

Comment: did you try sending the requestin using the browser WITHOUT those additional parameters? should be the exact same result.

Comment: as i stated there is nothing wrong with the api call and all these parameters are fine. it's returning correct results too, in both cases. only issue was that one field was translated into my local language. but issue is resolved now as i stated in my answer.

Comment: i know that. just saying, you are probably using some redundant parameters ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my language setting in which i had set "**language i understand**" to Urdu and didn't set "**which languages do you not want automatically translated**". By setting "which languages do ...." to "English" issue resolved but the funny thing is that, this issue only occurred when i called it in my Ruby on Rails application. Result was all in English when i hit same service through my browser or through graph API explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you read about "country_code", but according to the docs it´s the "locale" parameter:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

For example: `locale=en_US`

Comment: i am talking about result.

Comment: the result language changes with the locale parameter. not sure if it works with every api call, but i have tested it in other ones and it´s in the docs too. the parameter you have used (country_code) does not even exist.

Comment: parameter exists and it's returning correct results. there was only one issue. the response is a list of cities and in a city there is a field "country_name" which was automatically translated into my local language. there is nothing wrong with api call.

Comment: can you point me to the docs where those parameters are mentioned? i´d really like to know that for the future.